# ¿De que forma puedo añadir una bandera si un registro hermano contiene determinado valor?

Tags: sql-server

Estoy intentando traer información de una tabla `pedidos`, basándome en el valor de los registros de una tabla `pedido_detalle`, mi condición principal es traerme los registros de `pedidos` donde `pedido detalle` contenga el producto con `id = 4`
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
DECLARE
    @inid date = '2018-01-01',
    @endd  date = '2018-12-31'

SELECT 
    P.Id_Pedido pedido, 
    CAST(RP.fecha AS datetime) + CAST(RP.tiempo AS datetime) fechasurtido,
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN PD.id_producto_confirmado IS NOT NULL THEN PD.id_producto_confirmado 
            ELSE PD.id_producto_entregado 
        END
    ) producto,
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN PD.cantidad_confirmado IS NOT NULL THEN PD.cantidad_confirmado
            ELSE PD.cantidad_entregada 
        END
    ) cantidad
FROM Pedido P
INNER JOIN Radios_Pedidos RP ON (RP.Id_Pedido = P.Id_Pedido) AND (RP.fecha BETWEEN @inid AND @endd) AND RP.id_radios = (
    SELECT TOP 1 r.id_radios
    FROM Radios_Pedidos r
    WHERE r.id_pedido = P.Id_Pedido AND r.tipo = 'ENTREGA'
    ORDER BY CAST(r.fecha AS datetime) + CAST(r.tiempo AS datetime) DESC
)
INNER JOIN Pedido_Detalle PD ON (PD.Id_Pedido = P.Id_Pedido) AND (
    CASE 
        WHEN PD.id_producto_confirmado IS NOT NULL THEN PD.id_producto_confirmado 
        ELSE PD.id_producto_entregado 
    END
) = 4
WHERE P.status_pedido = 1 AND P.Completo = 1
```

Hasta el momento este código me resulta muy eficiente dado que me devuelve todos los pedidos del año (cerca de 30k) en tan solo un segundo.
Mi problema es al querer añadir una bandera a la consulta cuando el pedido detalle ademas de cumplir la condición, cumple otra. He intentado añadir un `outer apply`

```
DECLARE
    @inid date = '2018-01-01',
    @endd  date = '2018-12-31'

SELECT 
    P.Id_Pedido pedido, 
    CAST(RP.fecha AS datetime) + CAST(RP.tiempo AS datetime) fechasurtido,
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN PD.id_producto_confirmado IS NOT NULL THEN PD.id_producto_confirmado 
            ELSE PD.id_producto_entregado 
        END
    ) producto,
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN PD.cantidad_confirmado IS NOT NULL THEN PD.cantidad_confirmado
            ELSE PD.cantidad_entregada 
        END
    ) cantidad,
    gas.tienegas
FROM Pedido P
INNER JOIN Radios_Pedidos RP ON (RP.Id_Pedido = P.Id_Pedido) AND (RP.fecha BETWEEN @inid AND @endd) AND RP.id_radios = (
    SELECT TOP 1 r.id_radios
    FROM Radios_Pedidos r
    WHERE r.id_pedido = P.Id_Pedido AND r.tipo = 'ENTREGA'
    ORDER BY CAST(r.fecha AS datetime) + CAST(r.tiempo AS datetime) DESC
)
INNER JOIN Pedido_Detalle PD ON (PD.Id_Pedido = P.Id_Pedido) AND (
    CASE 
        WHEN PD.id_producto_confirmado IS NOT NULL THEN PD.id_producto_confirmado 
        ELSE PD.id_producto_entregado 
    END
) = 4
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT 1 tienegas
    FROM Pedido_Detalle d
    WHERE d.Id_Pedido = PD.Id_Pedido AND 
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN d.id_producto_confirmado IS NOT NULL THEN d.id_producto_confirmado 
            ELSE d.id_producto_entregado 
        END
    ) IN (2, 3, 9)
) gas
WHERE P.status_pedido = 1 AND P.Completo = 1
```

Pero la consulta se vuelve sumamente lenta superando los 5 minutos en ejecutarse, ¿de qué manera puedo optimizar esto?

En pocas palabras estoy intentando devolver una columna (bit?) que me indique si los pedidos de producto 4 también contienen productos con id 2, 3 o 9

Comment: Escribí una respuesta, sin embargo te recomiendo leer como crear un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi opinión, el optimizador de consultas no logra encontrar un buen plan de ejecución, debido a la manera en que está construido el query. Sugiero simplificar y realizar la *detección* de este *registro hermano* que llamas, y finalmente sobre eso construir el resto de tu consulta.

Voy a realizar un par de ejemplos simplificados, que yo intentaría para optimizar el tiempo de ejecución.

Por ejemplo, voy a crear dos CTE, una conteniendo los pedidos que tienen el producto 4 y otro conteniendo los pedidos que tienen los productos 2, 3 o 9. Luego, puedo hacer un join entre estos para determinar si un pedido X tiene ambos *grupos* de productos.

Finalmente hago un select que me dice los pedidos que tienen el artículo 4, y un flag (bit) que me indica si tienen productos 2, 3 o 9. Sobre el resultado de esta consulta, puedo construir el resto del reporte.

```
with
PedidoCon4 as (
select distinct a.Id_Pedido
  from Pedido_Detalle a 
 where coalesce(a.id_producto_confirmado, a.id_producto_entregado) = 4
)
,
PedidoCon239 as (
select distinct a.Id_Pedido
  from Pedido_Detalle a 
 where coalesce(a.id_producto_confirmado, a.id_producto_entregado) in (2,3,9)
)
select   a.Id_Pedido
       , cast(case when b.Id_Pedido is not null then 1 else 0 end as bit) FlagTiene239
  from PedidoCon4 a
       left join PedidoCon239 b on b.Id_Pedido = a.Id_Pedido
```

Si esto aún resulta sub-optimo, yo suelo valerme de tablas temporales, creo algún índice sobre ellas y con esto suele optimizarse la consulta.

Siguiendo la misma idea, por ejemplo:

```
select distinct a.Id_Pedido
  into #PedidoCon4
  from Pedido_Detalle a 
 where coalesce(a.id_producto_confirmado, a.id_producto_entregado) = 4;

select distinct a.Id_Pedido
  into #PedidoCon239
  from Pedido_Detalle a 
 where coalesce(a.id_producto_confirmado, a.id_producto_entregado) in (2,3,9)

create index p239idx1 on #PedidoCon239 (Id_Pedido);

select   a.Id_Pedido
       , cast(case when b.Id_Pedido is not null then 1 else 0 end as bit) FlagTiene239
  from #PedidoCon4 a
       left join #PedidoCon239 b on b.Id_Pedido = a.Id_Pedido;
```

El resultado es el mismo, pero la este último tiende a ser más rápida con volúmenes grandes de datos o relaciones complejas que el optimizador no logra ajustar.

Hasta que tengo este resultado, que por lo que puedo ver es el más voluminoso en término de número de registros, ya hago el resto de joins y termino de construir la consulta.

Incluso puedo poner este resultado también en una tabla temporal y crearle un índice para hacerla más rápida, eso siempre en base a los resultados que voy obteniendo.

En reglas generales, en términos de ejecución óptima, es difícil dar una respuesta general. Puede ser que con tu consulta actual se pueda lograr una mejor ejecución simplemente añadiendo un índice, añadiendo un hint o haciendo algún otro cambio al SQL, en general es buena idea que aprendas a analizar el plan de ejecución y experimentes, pues el resultado depende mucho del conjunto, volumen y motor de datos particular sobre el que se aplica.